# A língua portuguesa tem algum sinônimo sem o estrangeirismo "performance" para "auto performance"?

Tags: etimologia, estrangeirismos, sinônimos

A palavra *performance* me incomoda um pouco, porque quando a vejo sendo utilizada, poderia facilmente ser substituída por uma palavra em português. Por exemplo, nas frases:

> Esse código é muito lento, a ***performance*** não está boa.
> O que justifica a má ***performance*** desta empresa na bolsa de valores?
> A ***performance*** daquela atriz foi excepcional!

a palavra *performance* poderia ser substituída por *desempenho* ou *atuação*:

> Esse código é muito lento, o **desempenho** não está bom.
> O que justifica o mau **desempenho** desta empresa na bolsa de valores?
> A **atuação** daquela atriz foi excepcional!

Porém, no nicho de *coaching*, com certa frequência escuto *auto performance*.

Busquei a definição no [Dicionário Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/auto%20performance), lá diz que esta palavra é reconhecida pelo FLiP, mas que ainda não se encontra no Dicionário Priberam. Também não encontrei a definição no [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/auto%20performance), [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=auto%20performance), [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/pesquisa.php?q=auto%20performance) e nem no [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/auto%20performance).

Então busquei pela definição fora dos dicionários. Uma que encontrei no site [O Livre](https://olivre.com.br/alta-performance-ou-auto-performance) é:

> Auto performance, que nada mais é do que a capacidade de ter a consciência dos seus limites e de aceitá-los, mas não os deixar acomodar, e a partir disso, fazer intervenções necessárias, para o desenvolvimento de habilidades que o conduzirá a um bom resultado.

A língua portuguesa possui algum sinônimo para "auto performance"? Além disso, existe um motivo para "auto performance" ter surgido ao invés de "auto desempenho", por exemplo?

Comment: Acho meio gozado que auto performance queira dizer reconhecer seus própios limites. Isso é invenção desse pessoal. Outra coisa, você não gosta de performance mas aceita *coaching* que simplesmente é treinamento? Para mim, esse uso de auto é bobagem.

Comment: Do modo que vejo sendo usado no Brasil, talvez *coaching* seja treinamento, mas treinamento não é *coaching*, são coisas diferentes e não convém tratar aqui. Eu não gosto de *performance* por ter uma palavra que representa exatamente a mesma coisa (são termos intercambiáveis), mas aceito-a e provavelmente uso-a de vez em quando.

Comment: Rafael e @Lambie, "Acho meio gozado que auto performance queira dizer reconhecer seus própios limites" -- my thoughts exactly; até pensei que fosse uma redução de *autoavaliação de desempenho*, termo comum e que não anda lá muito afastado da definição dada n'O Livre; ou adaptação às três pancadas de *self-performance assessment*, deixando de fora a palavra chave. Mas parece que há para aí mesmo uma *autoperformance* que não é bem o mesmo que *autoavaliação de performance*. Encontrei o termo *self-performance*, possível fonte de *autoperformance*, nas não consegui encontrar explicação.

Comment: @Jacinto: self-performance is not really a term. self-assessment of performance is.

Comment: Primeiro você diz que não gosta de performance, e depois que gosta? Sim, treinamento é coaching. O que faz o treinador em esportes o qualquer outra atividade.

Comment: O termo "auto performance" é usado para além da autoavaliação (autoavaliação + melhorar nos aspectos avaliados, algo do tipo). Por exemplo, o título do livro [Os 10 maiores segredos para auto performance](https://www.amazon.com.br/maiores-segredos-para-auto-performance/dp/B094T6266N), não é "os 10 maiores segredos para a autoavaliação". Não encontrei uma equivalência em inglês nem uma boa referência em português. Não sei, fiz a pergunta com boa intenção mas está causando um tumulto nos comentários. Me parece que não há exatamente uma resposta para minha dúvida.

Comment: Rafael, não te alarmes com a quantidade de comentários. Não é nada de extraordinário. É uma pergunta válida.

Comment: The question is valid. There is not a term in English that is "auto-performance". An individual has his or her performance.  Many individuals have performances. And you can self-assess your (own) performance or get someone else to assess it. So, all I can think is that the Brazilian phrase means: auto-evaluação de desempenho (de performance). Não há tumulto. Estou tentando responder com que sei.  A realidade as vezes é complicada.....é assim mesmo.

Comment: Rafael, ecoo o Jacinto: não se encabule com a extensão da discussão, neologismos às vezes são mais polêmicos mesmo — tuas contribuições têm sido positivas até agora e essa é mais uma delas. Mas confesso que também estranho a expressão, pois as palavras não parecem de imediato denotar o significado dado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No exemplo dado

> Auto performance, que nada mais é do que a capacidade de ter a consciência dos seus limites e de aceitá-los, mas não os deixar acomodar, e a partir disso, fazer intervenções necessárias, para o desenvolvimento de habilidades que o conduzirá a um bom resultado

Isto parece referir-se a [metacognição](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacogni%C3%A7%C3%A3o) que é um área de estudo dentro da psicologia. Ou seja, os sinónimos correctos seriam capacidede de *auto-crítica* ou *auto-análise* ou *auto-reflexão* pode também por vezes chamar-se *meditação*, etc...

Lendo literatura especializada em psicologia irão emergir termos técnicos e formas prevalentes de referir-se à *metacognição* dependendo sobre o que o agente pensante toma por objecto de reflexão e como conduz essa reflexão. Decerto na literatura sobre gestão e contabilidade haverá também termos técnicos específicos sobre qual parte da empresa é avalidade, segundo que indicadores, e como é conduzida a avaliação - tipo *auditoria interna*.

> O que justifica a má performance desta empresa na bolsa de valores?

Por exemplo aqui pode dizer-se apreciou ou depreciou a *cotação*, a *capitalização em bolsa*, *o valor das acções*.

Também na [engenharia do controlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory) usariam-se uma multiplicidade de termos consoante o que o sistema faça, como é implementado e o que controla. *Precisão*, *rapidez*, *eficiência*, *taxa de erro*, *tempo de resposta* do qual o sistema ia proceder a uma *auto-correcção* melhorando um dos indicadores.

> Porém, no nicho de coaching, com certa frequência escuto auto performance.

Talvez esteja aqui o problem porque *coaching* é também um neologismo vago que refere uma forma de *ensino*, de *mentorado*, de *acompanhamento*, de *formação*. Frequentemente é usado para expressar uma relação de ensino que se pretende não formalizar verbalmente com demasiado rigor por ser circunstancial, pontual, ou por não se inserir nas formas mais tradicionais de acompanhamento de um discente ou formando.

Concordo que *auto performance* é um termo vago que veicula pouco significado e pode facilmente ser dispensado mediante um uso mais rigoroso da linguagem.

Comment: Reflexão muito mais interessante que minha resposta pedestre.

Comment: @stafusa a tua resposta foi muito fixe, eu não me ia lembrar das palavras que incluíste.

Comment: Não conhecia o termo *metacognição*, realmente me parece bastante relacionado com o significado de *auto performance*. Apesar de eu achar que os sinônimos propostos definem apenas metade de *auto performance*, este é um termo bem menos conhecido do que eu achava que fosse. Creio que em uma conversa qualquer, possa parecer vago de fato.

Answer (score 3):

Esse neologismo está longe de estar estabelecido na língua: o Google retorna apenas 54 páginas brasileiras com o termo, e *todas*, com exceção de "O livre", são relacionadas a carros automotores. Também o [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/now/) não possui nenhum registro da expressão.

De qualquer modo, uma possibilidade, apesar de menos específica que a definição dada, poderia ser [autoconhecimento](https://dicionario.priberam.org/autoconhecimento) ou algum sinônimo:

> Conhecimento de si próprio. = AUTOGNOSE, AUTOGNOSIA, HEAUTOGNOSE

Comment: [Autoconsciência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconsci%C3%AAncia) e também seria engraçado [autocognoscência](https://www.google.com/search?q=autocognoscência). @Stafusa cê é um cara auto-cognoscitivo pensa automático :)

Comment: @bad_coder Hahaha... sim, seria engraçado.